# How to access View helper in integration test in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, view, font-awesome

I have following code in my Rails view

```
 <li><span class="list-group-item-bullet"><%= icon('eye') %></span>
```

which generates following HTML:

```
<li><span class="list-group-item-bullet"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
```

I want to verify this thing in my integration test and I am using the following code which is generating an error

```
 assert_select 'li' do
   assert_select 'span.list-group-item-bullet', 'i.fa fa-eye'
 end
```

How can I verify it in my integration test?

Comment: I think you just forgot the 'dot' to identify `fa-eye` as a class: `assert_select 'span.list-group-item-bullet', 'i.fa.fa-eye'`

Comment: No, i try your solution as well, but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below seems to work:

```
assert_select 'li' do
  assert_select 'span.list-group-item-bullet' do
    assert_select 'i.fa.fa-eye'
  end
end
```

Or more concisely,

```
assert_select 'li span.list-group-item-bullet i.fa.fa-eye'
```

Taglia was correct that you need 'i.fa.fa-eye' b/c 'i.fa fa-eye' looks for an i tag with class fa and a descendent fa-eye tag.